# Raspberry : How use two monitors?

Tags: raspbian, display

How can I use two monitors on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 ?

Not the DSI Display but two monitors like we do on windows by extending the display.

---

[image]

This what I have now on my raspberry pi 3 Model B
But I have a bad resolution on the secondary monitor (At right on the picture)

This is the code of my xorg.conf file :

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "displaylink"
        Driver          "fbturbo"
        Option          "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
        Option          "ShadowFB" "off"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Raspberry Pi HDMI"
        Driver          "fbturbo"
        Option          "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
        Option          "ShadowFB" "off"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "PHILIPS 221E"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "PHILIPS Brilliance 220SW"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "screen"
        Device          "displaylink"
        Monitor         "PHILIPS Brilliance 220SW"
        DefaultDepth    16
        SubSection      "Display"
                Depth   16
                Virtual 1680 1050
                Modes   "1680x1050"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "screen1"
        Device          "Raspberry Pi HDMI"
        Monitor         "PHILIPS 221E"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "default"
        Screen          0 "screen1" 0 0
        Screen          1 "screen" RightOf "screen1"
        Option          "Xinerama" "true"
EndSection
```

And In the /boot/config.txt file I add the line

framebuffer_depth=16

How can I reslove this problem of resolution screen ?

Comment: You probably have to get extra hardware, as in USB display port. The output HDMI only supports one Display attached to it.

Comment: So with two waveshare 7" touch panels HDMI panels, an HDMI splitter and a raspberry pi zero w, I can mirror the display. I don't know how to extend the screen across two HDMI panels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds it is possible using an extra board plugged on the gpio and it outputs a VGA output.
see more info on [gert 666 board](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gert-vga-adapter/)
You also need to have a software that support it. There are some patch described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=94424&start=125#p1169983)
It seems not really straightforward.

Comment: I found this website who talk about how use two screen on a raspi: https://www.novaspirit.com/2015/12/31/low-end-tech-how-to-setup-dual-monitor-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I follow this proceed with the OS Ubuntu Mate 16.04 installed on my Raspberry Pi 3. But Only the second screen (DisplayLink USB Adapter) display the content of raspberry. The first screen (HDMI Port) are black with a white command prompt. Do you know what can I do resolve that ?

Comment: looks like the hdmi is not reckognized. maybe this link can explain: http://blog.mivia.dk/solved-hdmi-working-raspberry-pi/. There is maybe something similar for ubuntu

Comment: This can maybe also come from a power supply that can not power both HDMI and USB ports.

Comment: The first monitor (Philips Brilliance 220SW) who is connect by the port hdmi is power on but display nothing, just a flashing white line. The second monitor (Philips Brilliance 220SW) display the content of the raspberry but not with a good resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I follow this proceed:

https://www.novaspirit.com/2015/12/31/low-end-tech-how-to-setup-dual-monitor-on-raspberry-pi/

After I download the driver from DisplayLink:

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

I install it and update the Xorg packages too.

This is what I have in my file xorg.conf (/etc/X11/xorg.conf)

```
Section "Device" 
# RPi builtin video, framebuffer 0
  Identifier "rpi" 
  driver "fbdev" 
  Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0" 
  Option "ShadowFB" "off"
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
# USB DisplayLink video, framebuffer 1
  Identifier "uga" 
  driver "fbdev" 
  Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1" 
  Option "ShadowFB" "off"
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
# Primary monitor.
  Identifier "Philips" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
# Secondary monitor.
  Identifier "Philips" 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
  Identifier "primary" 
  Device "rpi" 
  Monitor "Philips" 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
  Identifier "secondary" 
  Device "uga" 
  Monitor "Philips" 
EndSection 

Section "ServerLayout" 
  Identifier "default" 
  Screen 0 "primary" 0 0
  Screen 1 "secondary" RightOf "primary"
EndSection
```

The two monitors (Philips Brilliance 220SW) are power on and work great, but my keyboard and my mouse don't work. How can I do to resolve that ? I can't login...

Comment: Hello! Formatting here uses markdown and a bit of HTML, see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: So you are using an EXTRA USB device here? Not connection into the single HDMI port? Sounds like it.

Comment: No, I use a usb adapter Kensingston DisplayLink Certified for my second monitor Philips. The first monitor is connected to the HDMI port.

Comment: So somebody know how I can have access to my keyboard and mouse ?